# How can I debug a codebuild container?

Tags: codebuild

I ran locally `codebuild` a `buildspec.yml`, but what is the advantage now to run it locally? Am I able to debug the container?

Comment: Running codebuild locally allows you to test your build environment and troubleshoot any potential issues before deploying. While you can't directly debug the container, you can examine logs and artifacts to understand the behavior of your build.

Comment: @Talha But I can do this in aws, too. What is the difference?

Comment: The key difference is the level of convenience. Running CodeBuild locally allows you to debug and fix issues without worrying about the cost or time constraints, which can be quite beneficial in a large development environment.